# No Job Title or Job Description - Help

Tags: resume, career-development, careers, title, job-description

I've been at my current job for a little over 7 years with no job title or job description. No one has a description and I've been told they have no idea what they would give me as a title. Updating my resume is becoming a challenge, as is knowing if I were to look for a new position...what exactly am I considered? My research keeps leading me to possibly a Comptroller? Unfortunately, I have no college degree but am more than willing to start working toward one or at least a certificate.

My company has approximately 25 employees with annual sales of roughly $14M. I am one person handling and responsible for all A/P, A/R, Credit/Risk Mgmt, banking and financial statements reconciliation, sales tax filings, preparation of monthly, quarterly and year end statements and consolidation with global subsidiaries. Responsible for maintenance of all company records and documents. Oversee/approve purchasing.

All HR responsibilities are mine as well which include our benefits (health, dental, life ins, 401K) some payroll, employee records, accident/OSHA reports, liaison with accountants, attorneys and insurance brokers. General insurance policies, oversee/management of our fleet of 12 vehicles.  I am the point of contact for all building and facility, phone system, office equipment matters, repairs, projects.

I report to (2) VP's and our Director overseas monitors and guides financials quarterly.

My goal is to be able to update my resume with a proper title and job description and possibly help me figure out what sort of position I could potentially look for. I suppose I'm having a career path identity crisis! Any advice or thoughts would be tremendously appreciated.

Comment: I imagine that you would have all types of issues outside of your work as well. I think if you are not given a title then it means you are free to come up with what you think is suitable. But these days creative titles are also quite popular and show that you are imaginative and innovative to the potential employers.

Comment: Make it "Office Manager". Your responsibilities include bookkeeping and HR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you do HR, Benefits Administration, Accounting, Compliance and Executive Business Administration. You can probably use any one (**or more**) of those titles on your resume legitimately.

Titles aren't always very exact; there can be a lot of variation in duties for the same title between organizations. They're also fairly localized. It wouldn't be a bad move to check job descriptions for those titles and see how well they match up with your experience.